# React cannot fetch data from Express

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express

I'm learning `React` and `Express` with that said I am working on my learning application which just takes data from `MySQL` and then Visualize it.

So, I made simple express server with router:

```js
//controllers.js
const getData = async (SQL) => {
  try {
    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(SQL, (err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(res);
      });
    });
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};

//router.js 
router.get("/CB/fridge01", (req, res, next) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM fridge01";
  getData(sql)
    .then((result) => res.json(result))
    .catch((err) => res.json(err));
});

//index.js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/api", router);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("localhost:" + port + "/api/CB/fridge01");
});


app.listen(port, (error) => {
  error
    ? console.log(`An error occurred: ${error}`)
    : console.log(`The server has started at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

And then in my react component I just use ComponentDidMount to execute fecth api:

```js
componentDidMount() {
     //192.168.88.169 is my local IP and port 8080 is setup in index.js
    fetch("192.168.88.169:8080/api/CB/fridge01", { method: "GET" })
      .then((res) => {
        res
          .json()
          .then((json) => {
            this.setState({ metrics: json });
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

and it gives me an error in console saying: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

When I open my express with `curl` or `postman` or even browser, I get the same data:

```json
[{"id":1,"recorded":"2021-11-22T11:16:22.000Z"}]
```

these are just sample data i hardcoded into DB table

Thank you for your help and patience and please excuse my grammar skills.

Comment: In the browser, open the console / inspector (F12 / Ctrl + Shift + I / Inspect this), go to "Network" tab and check Response. It is very possible that you are missing one of the headings.  BTW: Why do you go down to `then()` andyou're approaching callback-hell. Use    chain `.then(reap=>resp.json()).then(json=> {this.setState({ metrics: json })} ).catch(/*only one*/)`

Comment: I am learning stuff by doing mistakes like this, never used Promises async/await before. 
So, I opened the `network` part of console and guess what I found, the URL fetch is getting data from is this: `http://localhost:3000/192.168.88.169:8080/api/CB/fridge01` which is total bullsh*t
I fixed that by typing protocol in front of requested IP `fetch(http://....)` .Now I am getting Cors error (I fixed that by using: `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); `). 

Its working now, thank you. Anyway, how do I close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with `fetch` API on react side. Instead of fetching data from `192.168.88.169:8080/...` I was fetching from `localhost:3000/192.168...`

To fix this I put `http` protocol into fetching URL. (`fetch("http://192...")`)

Then I simply allowed CORS and voila!